# Exclude derived source files from Xbase class-path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, xtext

I have DSL written in Xtext, where is use Xbase to implement expressions. To generate code, I use the JVM model inferring mechanisms. But since the project is build by Maven, I do not use the Xtext builder to build my project in Eclipse, but rely on a Maven plugin I wrote to compile my DSL files.
The output of the Maven plugin is then added to the Build-Path of my Eclipse project so that I can use it in other Eclipse projects.

Problems occur if once I am editing a DSL file for which the Maven plugin already generated Java files, since the Xtext inferring now has two versions of the inferred type available. One version that was just inferred by itself and one that was generated by the Maven plugin and is available on the Build-Path.
The results are phantom-errors that do only appear in the DSL editor.

One fix that comes to mind is to instruct the Xbase scoping somehow to ignore types that resist in derived resources, as those generated by the Maven plugin. How can I achieve that?

With kind regards,
Jan

PS: The project setup is kind of unchangeable. So relying on the Xtext builder is not an option.

Comment: Xtext editors won't work without the Xtext builder, so it must be enabled, but you should be able to disable code generation for your language in Eclipse, look for preferences.

Comment: In fact the DSL editor is already running in production without the Xtext project builder. Also I did not exclude the Xtext builder because of its code generation.

I was looking for a way to configure the classpath Xbases uses inside the editor.